# :8080 frontend POST to :5000 flask backend blocked by CORS (docker-compose)

Tags: python, docker, flask, cors

I have my frontend and backend running in separate containers. I can access both, however, when trying to perform a POST from the React frontend -> Flask backend, I get blocked by CORS.

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/api/upload' from origin `
>   'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I've been trying to get this going with Flask-Cors but still get the same error after many attempts.

Here is my flask application.py:

```
# Start with a basic flask app webpage.
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, copy_current_request_context, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import os

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['gz'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
CORS(app, resources=r'/api/*')

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(headers=['Content-Type'])
def fileUpload():
    target=os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER,'test_docs')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)
    file = request.files['file'] 
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        destination="/".join([target, filename])
        file.save(destination)
        response="Whatever you wish too return"
    else:
        response="File not parsed."
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```